# Last Post Function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I made my website http://test.costa.io/?page_id=4, with wordpress and I put here all my post. The problem is that I want to have a function to check if its the last post, and if it's so dont put the `/hr/`.

I tried with the function `more_post()` and `last_post` but didn't make it work.

This is the code of the plugin I use to get all the post in the web :

http://pastebin.com/Qv9Ff2T7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of posts you have by `count($posts)` and then add a counter variable in the foreach loop. When the counter is equal to the number of posts you know that it's the last post, so don't output the `hr`.

Comment: Didnt make it work yet, probably my bad since im new to php.

Comment: //getting number of posts
$numposts = count($posts);
$numDone = 1;

  if($numDone<<$numposts){
  //close the post with a nice <hr>
  $out .= '</div>';   
  $out .= '<hr style="margin:10px 0">';
  $out .= '</div>';
  $out .= '<br>';
  $numDone=$numDome+1;
  }

Is this Correct?

Comment: This `$numDone = 1;` should go outside of the the foreach loop. And I don't know if it's only a typo but it should be `if($numDone < $numposts){`.

Comment: It's outside the loop, but inside the whole function... should be outside the function too ?

Comment: It should be in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I make it work changing the way I did it, still the count was a good way to do it, so ill give u the credit for it. Thanks everyone